# "[-4:]" O que é essa sintaxe?

Tags: python, sintaxe

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

```
namer = name[-4:]
```

Onde `name` recebe um nome , mas o que significa esse `[-4:]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isso é um *slice* (fatia). O código em questão retorna os últimos quatro caracteres da string.

Um *slice* segue o padrão `[começo:fim]`. `começo` e `fim` são índices começando do zero. O caractere do primeiro índice é incluído na fatia, já caractere do último índice não, i.e., a fatia inclui `começo` mas não inclui `fim`.

- Quando começo é deixado em branco isso significa "retorne tudo desde o começo da string".
- Quando o fim é deixado em branco isso significa "retorne tudo até o fim da string".
- Quando colocamos um sinal de negativo na frente de um índice isso significa "conte a quantidade de caracteres a partir do fim da string ao invés do começo".

Então `[-4:]` significa "retorne a fatia a partir do quarto último índice até o fim da string".

*Slicing* pode ser usado com outros tipos além de string (e.g., uma lista), além disso *slicing* possui um terceiro parâmetro opcional para o incremento do passo (fatiamento estendido), porém isso está fora do escopo da pergunta .

Comment: Só faria um adendo de que um _slice_ pode ser `[começo:fim:passo]`, sendo o último parâmetro o pulo do slice. (: