# Limitando a quantidade de caracteres em uma string em Python

Tags: python

Galera, tenho um script em Python que durante o processamento de informações está gerando string com muitos caracteres e preciso de cada uma string para criar uma pasta com seu "nome". Mas não se prendão ao problema, pois o que quero mesmo saber é como limito tal string a um tamanho desejado e armazena-la em uma variável. Por exemplo:

```
stringGrande = "gerando string com muitos caracteres e preciso de cada"
stringPequena = stringGrande (limitada)
print stringPequena

Resultado: gerando string com muitos
```

por exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O tipo *string* é iterável no Python e permite acessar seu conteúdo via *slices*. Por exemplo, `texto[1:5]` iria retornar do primeiro ao quarto caractere de `texto`.

```
>>> print('anderson'[1:5])
nder
```

Se você omitir o primeiro valor, o Python irá entender que é zero, começando a partir do início do texto:

```
>>> print('anderson'[:5])
ander
```

Já, se o valor informado após os dois pontos exceder o tamanho do texto, será retornado apenas até o final do mesmo:

```
>>> print('anderson'[1:30])
nderson
```

Desta forma, para limitar um texto a um número `N` de caracteres, basta fazer `texto[:N]`.

Leitura adicional:

- ["[-4:]" O que é essa sintaxe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96604/5878)

Answer (score 2):

```
stringGrande = "gerando string com muitos caracteres e preciso de cada"


def diminuir(str):
    max = 10 # Numero Maximo de caracteres Permitidos.
    if len(str) > max:
        return str[:max]
    else:
        return str


stringPequena = diminuir(stringGrande)
print stringPequena
```