# Preciso de ajuda para limitar a quantidade de caracteres em python kivy

Tags: python-kivy

Estou com uma pequena quantidade, estou tentando limitar a quantidade de caracteres que podem ser digitados sem texto, por exemplo, um código de DDD, onde basta apenas 2 ou 3 dígitos, limitar para apenas no máximo 3 números, mas não estou obtindo, tentei realizar da Em segundo lugar, mas também não funcionou, a ideia era agora limitar pelo próprio script kivy, obrigado até mais pessoal: D

Código Kivy
TextInput:

```
    id: dd
    pos_hint:{"center_x":.35, "center_y":.2}
    size_hint:(.1,.05)
    multiline:False
    write_tab: False
    input_filter:'int'
```

Python de código
dd = self.root.ids.dd.text

dd = maxlength (2)

Comment: Recomendo ler: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303296/limitando-a-quantidade-de-caracteres-em-uma-string-em-python

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Limitando a quantidade de caracteres em uma string em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303296/limitando-a-quantidade-de-caracteres-em-uma-string-em-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tipo *string* é iterável no Python e permite acessar seu conteúdo via *slices*. Por exemplo, `texto[1:5]` iria retornar do primeiro ao quarto caractere de `texto`.

```
>>> print('anderson'[1:5])
nder
```

Se você omitir o primeiro valor, o Python irá entender que é zero, começando a partir do início do texto:

```
>>> print('anderson'[:5])
ander
```

Já, se o valor informado após os dois pontos exceder o tamanho do texto, será retornado apenas até o final do mesmo:

```
>>> print('anderson'[1:30])
nderson
```

Desta forma, para limitar um texto a um número `N` de caracteres, basta fazer `texto[:N]`.

Leitura adicional:

- ["[-4:]" O que é essa sintaxe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96604/5878)
- [Limitando a quantidade de caracteres em uma string em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/303296/)

## OBS:

No seu caso acho que o código que você quer ficaria +- assim :

```
n = input("Digite o numero com DDD: (sem caracteres especial)")
```

-Entrada: 0011111111

```
print ('DDD:',n[:2])
```

-Saida: DDD: 00

```
print ('numero:',n[2:])
```

-Saida: numero: 11111111

recomendo fazer um regEx ou uma mascara no seu input assim não corre risco do usuário digitar errado

Comment: Se a resposta é a mesma, basta você sinalizar a pergunta como duplicada. Não há porque ter múltiplas respostas com o mesmo conteúdo espalhado pelo site. Logo abaixo da pergunta há o botão "sinalizar", basta colocar que a pergunta deveria ser fechada por ser duplicada e indicar o link da outra pergunta.

Comment: Grata ^^ Sou nova usuária, ainda não sei como funciona o Stack